# Разработка мобильных приложений

Tags: phonegap, android, ios

Надо, чтоб разработка велась в одной среде, желательно с применением html+js без С, явы и т.п., на выходе приложение, которое работает под android, iOS, BlackBerry, Symbian OS, Windows Phone 7 и других.

Нашел такую штуку как [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com), не могу понять стоит проваливаться в её изучение или нет...

Подскажите софт для написания кроссплатформенных приложений.

Comment: Все эти жаваскриптовые поделки очень большая боль.

Не получится написать один раз, и чтоб работало потом везде. Под каждую платформу нужно будет что-то отпимизировать.

Comment: если Вам пару окошек с кнопками сделать, которые пару запросов к серверу сделают, тогда PhoneGap Ваш выбор. Если хотите серьезно заниматься, писать нормальный софт - тогда только с использованием SDK и под каждую платформу. Кроссплатформенная разработка - миф. Требования к дизайну у всех разные.

Comment: Ну как бы можно сделать дизайн отдельно, бизнес логику отдельно, в iOs оно так и должно быть по идее, тем более что по хорошему надо делать даже не по одному дизайну на платформу, а отдельный дизайн для планшетников и телефонов. Хотя если разобраться мое высказывание не более чем теоретизирование - нормальных кроссплатформенных средств пока вроде нет, из того что есть это qt (но он только-только до беты в андроиде дошел, а в iOs в альфе или даже в proof of concept), mosync (врать не буду - не использовал, но у него вроде только логика отдельно, а остальное нативно), про фонгеп уже dct сказали

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Рассказываю, чтобы не было иллюзий что есть who:

PhoneGap и проч. приблуды предназначены для написания программ не под телефон, а под браузер - сечёте разницу? Если не сечёто то поясняю: прога запускается строго под браузером (иногда это оч. умело скрыто) на том или ином аппарате. Есть такая мода с недавних пор называется HTML 5.0, которая по сути объявляет браузер не просто браузером, а как бы операционной средой. Отрыжкой этого подхода и является PhoneGap.

Я лично в эту идею не верю - верите вы или нет - это ваше личное дело. Если верите, берите Phonegap и начинайте без знания Java: голый HTML+JS и вперед.

В общем вопрос кроссплатформенной разработки под мобильные системы, как видите, вопрос строго религиозный.

Я бы порекомендовал вам все же таки взять Java/C#/C++/ObjectiveC и впрячься в нормальную разработку под Android/J2ME/WP7/Symbian/iOS или что там еще есть - ибо бесплатные шанежек не бывает.

Не идите в секту сподвижников HTML 5.0 :)

Comment: Ну можно ведь как-то культернее написать?

Comment: @barmaley согласен с Вами полностью. Хотелось бы еще добавить, что если человек все таки знает JS, освоить Java не проблема в принципе. Но многие не знают что можно тоже самое реализовать с использованием стандартных средств разработки под ту или иную ОС, так как большинство браузеров на них поддерживает JS, и приложив немного усилий можно интегрировать свое веб приложение под определенную ОС.

Comment: Кстати работать будет намного быстрее чем с использованием библиотеки Phonegap. Я лично проверял загрузку одной и той же HTML через Cordova и стандартный WebView на андроид, так вот разница в 2 сек. А это более чем существенно! 
ОСООБО порадовала секта сподвижников HTML 5.0!

Comment: @1101_debian извиняюсь, если мое косноязычие задело ваши высокие чувства к Html 5.0 :)

Comment: @Barmaley, дело не в HTML 5, просто ваш ответ звучит очень грубо и непрофессионально.

Comment: Цитата:

    @Barmaley, дело не в HTML 5, просто ваш ответ звучит очень грубо и непрофессионально.

@1101_debian, приятно видеть такие строки на ХэшКоде. @Barmaley, вы действительно не понимаете, о чём речь?

Comment: @1101_debian, @Stanislaw Ну насчет грубости я может и согласен - перегнул. А вот насчет непрофессиональности: можно как-то расшифровать?

Comment: @Barmaley - phonegap и прочие, как вы выразились, приблуды, предназначены для написания простых приложений, коими, если быть до конца откровенными, является абсолютное большинство. btw основная идея ниразу не в html5, а в том, что-бы можно было повторно использовать код уже работающего в браузерном окружении приложения и отбросить необходимость изучения всяких джав тогда, когда в них нет необходимости.

Хотя я уже понял, это у вас такой стиль "тонкого" троллинга, в противном случае вы рассуждаете о том, чем не пользуетесь и чего сами толком не понимаете (e.g. рассуждаете непрофессионально)

Comment: @AlexWindHope Я в общем то не против того что эти "приблуды" для создания простых приложений. А вот насчет html5 вы неправы - то о чем вы пишете это как раз и есть основная идея html5 - придание браузеру функций операционной системы. В этой струе и лежат оси типа WebOS, ChromeOS. Верю, что разработчики PhoneGAP ни разу не руководствовались идеями html5, но по сути они находятся в том самом тренде: а именно сделать из браузера универсальную операционную среду.

Comment: @Barmaley, вы безнадежны :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope лишний раз в пользу моей правоты - раз нет аргументов, значит вопрос строго религиозный: из разряда верю - не верю :)

Comment: @Barmaley, не совсем, просто вам все-равно не докажешь, да и нет особого желания это делать

Answer (score 3):

Если говорить конкретно про Cordova(PhoneGap), то в любом случае Вам придется использовать Java вставки для Андроид, Си или С# для iOS и Windows Phone. Но есть главный плюс заключается в том, что основная работа будет проводиться с использованием HTML-CSS-JS, то есть грубо говоря вы создаете свое Web приложение и далее пристыковываете его на различные платформы, но в любом случае Вам необходимо будет иметь знания и навыки работы с различными платформами под которые вы хотите интегрировать Ваши приложения. Но Ваши приложения будут работать значительно медленнее нативных. Кроссплатформенность это, конечно, хорошо(в плане экономии времени), но Вы сами с самого начала лишаете свое приложение многих возможностей, хотя в последних версиях Cordova есть возможность работы с аппаратной частью Вашего устройства.

Comment: >> Но есть главный плюс заключается в том, что основная работа будет проводиться с использованием HTML-CSS-JS

я лично считаю это самым большим минусом. В особенности для батареи.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы.
Подскажите правильный подход к разработке, чтоб на выходе получить приложение работающее на всех платформах. Уже сутки гуглю и не могу вкурить как входить в тему мобильных разработок, чтоб не убить время при неправильном выборе софта для работы...

Comment: одно на всех? только приложение в браузере, но и то не факт.
Только делать на всех платформах независимо.

Comment: Плюс для тех кто на самом деле хочет использовать HTML-JS-CSS, но в результате выйдет тормозное и не всегда корректно работающее приложение. Это естественно минус. И я никогда не понимал людей знающих JS: в чем сложность при знаниях JS освоить ту же Java или C#. На начальном этапе они даже различий не заметят.

Comment: @KoVadim, хотя я и согласен с вашим утверждением насчет батареи, но, как показывает практика, батарею, в большей степени, потребляет не медленный код, а не нужный :)

Comment: @vanyamelikov потому что в этом далеко не всегда есть необходимость и мало кто готов за это платить?

Comment: @AlexWindHope значит нужно сводить кол-во ненужного кода к минимуму.

Comment: Не пригодятся (про вставки на java и др.) - https://build.phonegap.com/

Answer (score 3):

Делать это очень просто:

1. Пишете html код
2. Запаковываете в zip
3. Кидаете в https://build.phonegap.com/
4. Получаете установочные файлы на все платформы

А вообще я вам не советую юзать html. Когда я только-только знакомился с мобильной разработкой, я тоже считал phonegap светлой штукой. Ну написал я простое приложение на нём, пустил на своём девайсе (причём на мощном - SGN2). Так у него при переходе между страницами была задержка 3-5 секунд. Правда страницы были нагружены картинками, но тем ни менее 3 секунды это много. Сделал потом нативную версию - на загрузку страницы с тем же содержимым уходило не более 0.25 секунд

Answer (score 1):

Наверное проще всего зайти на официальные сайты, и курить их доки:

- [Symbian SDKs](http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/ec866fab-4b76-49f6-b5a5-af0631419e9c/S60_All_in_One_SDKs.html)
- [the latest version of the bada SDK to install bada IDE and helpful development tools.](http://developer.bada.com/devtools/sdk)
- [Windows Phone SDK](http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk)
- [Access additional resources in the iOS Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action)
- [Get the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/sdk/index.html)

Comment: По моему правильно было расставить ровно наоборот:

1. android
2. ios
3. winphone
4. bada
5. s60

Comment: Ну а вкладки в браузере стеком встали :-D

Answer (score 1):

Я бы еще посмотрел в сторону Adobe Air.
Он, конечно, не на всем работает, что вы перечислили, а только на Mac, PC, Android, iOS, Black Barry, но за то представляет собой инструмент посерьезнее, чем Phonegap(cordova).

Еще есть одна неприятная особенность - работает только на аппаратах, поддерживающих OpegGL ES 2.0
думаю, среди устройств, выпущенных после середины 2011 года таких окажется оч. мало.

Comment: Вторые сутки гугления... Дошёл до Adobe Air, пришел на хешкод задать вопрос про него, а тут ваш коммент по теме )..
В общем активное обсуждение Adobe Air на хабре в 2007-2009 году, потом как то всё затихло.. Adobe Air ещё жив вообще?

Если есть что под рукой - дайте пожалуйста наводку, как работать с Adobe Air используя js, html + css.
И ещё интересно будет ли тормозным приложение из пары html страниц(натыкался на негативные отзывы об Air)...

Comment: Никогда не слышал про JS и HTML  в AIR.
Может, конечно, и можно, но я пишу на AS3.

А на счет поддержки - для Android Air обновился последний раз вчера(15.05.2013)